# Short story about man who can fix anything except himself

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The narrator is a man who owns a restaurant. An unknown man comes in asking him for something (food and a room for the night, I think) and the narrator feels bad and want to help the man. The unknown man then fixes the narrator's refrigerator. After this, the narrator wishes to offer the unknown man food and board for the night.

However, the narrator's wife says that she feel uneasy about the unknown man. The unknown man then proceeds to fix her scale. With her scale fixed, she agrees to allow the man to stay the night.

As the story progresses, we find out that the unknown man can fix nearly anything. People visit the narrator's restaurant to have the unknown man fix their belongings. The narrator is happy to accommodate this, as the various townspeople usually buy food while they wait. Soon, the unknown man is even helping people fix their issues in life, including their relationships.

Eventually, the unknown man is overwhelmed. He runs to the bridge along with the narrator and it is implied that he wishes to commit suicide. A large crowd of people chase after him asking him to help them fix their things. The narrator realizes that this is the only way out for the man and the story ends with the unknown man jumping.

Can anyone identify this short story?

Comment: A wild shot.  Can this be Theodore Sturgeon, “Uncle Fremmis”, the story described in http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/47185/4918 Name of the Theodore Sturgeon short story about a man who can fix anything ?

Comment: @b_jonas I don't think that's the one - the narrator and character described in that question seem quite different as does the back story

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's "The Fix" by Percival Everett, from the collection "Damned If I Do".
That story ends:

> Sherman looked down at the peaceful water below. It was a long drop that no one could hope to survive. He looked at Douglas.
>
> Douglas nodded.
>
> The masses of people pressed in from either side. Sherman stepped over the railing and stood on the brink, the toes of his shoes pushed well over the edge.
>
> “Don’t!” they all screamed. “Fix us! Fix us!”

Comment: Why do you think that? Can you expand on how it meets the OP's criteria?

Comment: It's definitely the right story.  I've added a quote from the end to illustrate the match.